# How can I have access to an API data on nodeJS or juste JS from a curl request on the command line?

Tags: node.js, api, curl, request

I need to make a request to an API, on the documentation it tells me to use CURL.

I did that on command, and it worked fine.

My question is how can I use the result on a program ? I mean by that using the json data on a nodejs program to do some action on it. Like posting the data on a CRM for instance.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the API? You can make requests using Axios. There is an npm module that helps you to use the curl feature.

Comment: lemlist api a french emailing platform supplier

Comment: https://developer.lemlist.com/#authentication